# Django & Vue.js: GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 220 Not Found

Tags: django, webpack, vue.js

I am new to Django and Vue.js, and trying to combine those tow frameworks, So I followed a video tutoriel and copy every thing he does, except for the names of project, app, and variables, and had to copy only the webpack.config.js. So in the video, he made `homepage/games` as his main page, but I choosed to make `webapp/game` as my main page. 
and when ever I tipe `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in the browser, the data I extracted from my database are not showen and the PowerShell shows this error

> [06/Apr/2018 15:25:26] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 220
>   Not Found: /homepage/games

I don't rmember copying or writing **homepage** in any of my project files. 
and I really don't know whitch code I should post in here so you could answer me.
So please if anyone have any idea or wants me to post any code,please let me know in a comment.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index , name="index"),
url(r'^webapp/game$', views.game , name="game"),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import games

def index(request):
    game= games.objects.all()
    return render(request, "webapp/index.html", {"game": game})

def game(request):
    game= serialize("json", games.objects.all())
    return HttpResponse(game, content_type= "application/json")
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1> hello </h1>
<div class="exemple">
<exemple></exemple>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**PS:** here is the link of the video I followed 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxLZg4PqC8M

Comment: Share your urls.py file and views.py file.

Comment: Do a Find in your IDE and find anywhere you have the text 'homepage'

Comment: I did it on all files but found nothing

Comment: @khadija.EL what error do you see in console/terminal ? What is your project and app name ? I think webapp is your project/app name and there is issue with your urls.py file. Kindly answer my questions and if possible update question with your index.html file.also

Comment: my project name is 'challenge', and my app name is **webapp** . and that's what the console shows:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)                    127.0.0.1/:1
 Uncaught (in promise) wt